# Javascript & Laravel : Error concatenating routes inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Hi i'm having troubles generating link routes to edit and destroy with my ajax results, i have this **JS** code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#filtro1').on('change',function(){
    var filtro = $('#filtro1').val()
    var target = document.getElementById('resultados1')
    $.get('/usuarios/filtrar/'+filtro+'',function(response){
        var usuarios = response
        var template = ''
        target.innerHTML = ''
        for(i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++){
            template += '<tr><td>'+usuarios[i].nombre_u+'</td><td>'+usuarios[i].apellidos_u+'</td><td>'+usuarios[i].telefono_u+'</td><td>'+usuarios[i].telefono_u+'</td><td>'+usuarios[i].celular_u+'</td><td>'+usuarios[i].user_name+'</td><td><a href="{{ route("usuarios.edit",$parameters = '+usuarios[i].id+') }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{{ route("usuarios.destroy",$parameters = '+usuarios[i].id+') }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td></tr>'
        }
        target.innerHTML = template;
    });
});
```

This works fine it shows the results that i want, but the link routes to edit and destroy appears like this:

[image]

The template isn't concatenating the element id in the route

`<a href="{{ route("usuarios.edit",$parameters = '+usuarios[i].id+') }}">`

.. why? what's wrong? help me please !

Comment: Try to change your route function with this `route("usuarios.edit",array('id'=>1))`

Comment: Have you looked over here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Comment: you can't use js inside exclamation. So replace `'+usuarios[i].id+'` with php variable: `route("usuarios.edit", $id)`